# Ethernet CRC computation

Tags: c, crc, crc32

I've a small issue when computing a CRC by using two different methods.
The 1st method uses a tool which is called Hexprobe Multibyte Calculator.
The 2nd method uses a C program.

The CRC properties are given below:
- Pre-processing: 0
- Generator polynomial: 0x04C11DB7
- Post-processing: 0

Message expressed in binary is 0x01 0x02
CRC computed is equal to 0xDB9BFAB2 (1st method) but with the C program the value is not the same one...

```
int CRC32EthTbl[256] =
{
        0x00000000, 0x04C11DB7, 0x09823B6E, 0x0D4326D9, 0x130476DC, 0x17C56B6B, 0x1A864DB2, 0x1E475005,
        0x2608EDB8, 0x22C9F00F, 0x2F8AD6D6, 0x2B4BCB61, 0x350C9B64, 0x31CD86D3, 0x3C8EA00A, 0x384FBDBD,
        0x4C11DB70, 0x48D0C6C7, 0x4593E01E, 0x4152FDA9, 0x5F15ADAC, 0x5BD4B01B, 0x569796C2, 0x52568B75,
        0x6A1936C8, 0x6ED82B7F, 0x639B0DA6, 0x675A1011, 0x791D4014, 0x7DDC5DA3, 0x709F7B7A, 0x745E66CD,
        0x9823B6E0, 0x9CE2AB57, 0x91A18D8E, 0x95609039, 0x8B27C03C, 0x8FE6DD8B, 0x82A5FB52, 0x8664E6E5,
        0xBE2B5B58, 0xBAEA46EF, 0xB7A96036, 0xB3687D81, 0xAD2F2D84, 0xA9EE3033, 0xA4AD16EA, 0xA06C0B5D,
        0xD4326D90, 0xD0F37027, 0xDDB056FE, 0xD9714B49, 0xC7361B4C, 0xC3F706FB, 0xCEB42022, 0xCA753D95,
        0xF23A8028, 0xF6FB9D9F, 0xFBB8BB46, 0xFF79A6F1, 0xE13EF6F4, 0xE5FFEB43, 0xE8BCCD9A, 0xEC7DD02D,
        0x34867077, 0x30476DC0, 0x3D044B19, 0x39C556AE, 0x278206AB, 0x23431B1C, 0x2E003DC5, 0x2AC12072,
        0x128E9DCF, 0x164F8078, 0x1B0CA6A1, 0x1FCDBB16, 0x018AEB13, 0x054BF6A4, 0x0808D07D, 0x0CC9CDCA,
        0x7897AB07, 0x7C56B6B0, 0x71159069, 0x75D48DDE, 0x6B93DDDB, 0x6F52C06C, 0x6211E6B5, 0x66D0FB02,
        0x5E9F46BF, 0x5A5E5B08, 0x571D7DD1, 0x53DC6066, 0x4D9B3063, 0x495A2DD4, 0x44190B0D, 0x40D816BA,
        0xACA5C697, 0xA864DB20, 0xA527FDF9, 0xA1E6E04E, 0xBFA1B04B, 0xBB60ADFC, 0xB6238B25, 0xB2E29692,
        0x8AAD2B2F, 0x8E6C3698, 0x832F1041, 0x87EE0DF6, 0x99A95DF3, 0x9D684044, 0x902B669D, 0x94EA7B2A,
        0xE0B41DE7, 0xE4750050, 0xE9362689, 0xEDF73B3E, 0xF3B06B3B, 0xF771768C, 0xFA325055, 0xFEF34DE2,
        0xC6BCF05F, 0xC27DEDE8, 0xCF3ECB31, 0xCBFFD686, 0xD5B88683, 0xD1799B34, 0xDC3ABDED, 0xD8FBA05A,
        0x690CE0EE, 0x6DCDFD59, 0x608EDB80, 0x644FC637, 0x7A089632, 0x7EC98B85, 0x738AAD5C, 0x774BB0EB,
        0x4F040D56, 0x4BC510E1, 0x46863638, 0x42472B8F, 0x5C007B8A, 0x58C1663D, 0x558240E4, 0x51435D53,
        0x251D3B9E, 0x21DC2629, 0x2C9F00F0, 0x285E1D47, 0x36194D42, 0x32D850F5, 0x3F9B762C, 0x3B5A6B9B,
        0x0315D626, 0x07D4CB91, 0x0A97ED48, 0x0E56F0FF, 0x1011A0FA, 0x14D0BD4D, 0x19939B94, 0x1D528623,
        0xF12F560E, 0xF5EE4BB9, 0xF8AD6D60, 0xFC6C70D7, 0xE22B20D2, 0xE6EA3D65, 0xEBA91BBC, 0xEF68060B,
        0xD727BBB6, 0xD3E6A601, 0xDEA580D8, 0xDA649D6F, 0xC423CD6A, 0xC0E2D0DD, 0xCDA1F604, 0xC960EBB3,
        0xBD3E8D7E, 0xB9FF90C9, 0xB4BCB610, 0xB07DABA7, 0xAE3AFBA2, 0xAAFBE615, 0xA7B8C0CC, 0xA379DD7B,
        0x9B3660C6, 0x9FF77D71, 0x92B45BA8, 0x9675461F, 0x8832161A, 0x8CF30BAD, 0x81B02D74, 0x857130C3,
        0x5D8A9099, 0x594B8D2E, 0x5408ABF7, 0x50C9B640, 0x4E8EE645, 0x4A4FFBF2, 0x470CDD2B, 0x43CDC09C,
        0x7B827D21, 0x7F436096, 0x7200464F, 0x76C15BF8, 0x68860BFD, 0x6C47164A, 0x61043093, 0x65C52D24,
        0x119B4BE9, 0x155A565E, 0x18197087, 0x1CD86D30, 0x029F3D35, 0x065E2082, 0x0B1D065B, 0x0FDC1BEC,
        0x3793A651, 0x3352BBE6, 0x3E119D3F, 0x3AD08088, 0x2497D08D, 0x2056CD3A, 0x2D15EBE3, 0x29D4F654,
        0xC5A92679, 0xC1683BCE, 0xCC2B1D17, 0xC8EA00A0, 0xD6AD50A5, 0xD26C4D12, 0xDF2F6BCB, 0xDBEE767C,
        0xE3A1CBC1, 0xE760D676, 0xEA23F0AF, 0xEEE2ED18, 0xF0A5BD1D, 0xF464A0AA, 0xF9278673, 0xFDE69BC4,
        0x89B8FD09, 0x8D79E0BE, 0x803AC667, 0x84FBDBD0, 0x9ABC8BD5, 0x9E7D9662, 0x933EB0BB, 0x97FFAD0C,
        0xAFB010B1, 0xAB710D06, 0xA6322BDF, 0xA2F33668, 0xBCB4666D, 0xB8757BDA, 0xB5365D03, 0xB1F740B4
};

void ComputeCRC32Eth(int Prepro,
                     int PostPro,
                     const char* Buffer,
                     unsigned int Size,
                     int* CRC32)
{
/* Declaration of internal variables */
int   TmpCRC;

int   TmpLookupVal;     /* Lookup Table Value         */
unsigned int TmpIndex;  /* Lookup Table Index         */
unsigned int NbBytes;   /* Number of Bytes in the Msg */

const char* TmpPtr;     /* Handler on the Message */
unsigned char Tmp1Byte;

/* Initialization */
TmpCRC = Prepro;

/* Attach the Handler */
TmpPtr = Buffer;

/* Compute the CRC32 (Ethernet) */
for (NbBytes = 0; NbBytes < Size; NbBytes++)
{
    /* Compute the Index in the Lookup Table */
    Tmp1Byte = *TmpPtr;
    TmpIndex = TmpCRC & 0xFFU;
    TmpIndex = TmpIndex ^ Tmp1Byte;

    /* Retrieve the value from the Lookup Table */
    TmpLookupVal = CRC32EthTbl[TmpIndex];

    /* Binary-shift on the right the CRC value of 8 bits */
    TmpCRC = TmpCRC >> 8U;

    /* Compute the CRC */
    TmpCRC = TmpCRC ^ TmpLookupVal;

    /* Next Byte */
    TmpPtr++;
}

/* Update the CRC32 */
*CRC32 = TmpCRC ^ PostPro;

return;
}
```

Do you have any clue ?
By advance, thanks for your help
Phil

Comment: If this is actually Ethernet CRC, it needs to be bit reflected, initial CRC = 0xffffffff, and the CRC is post complemented.

Answer (score 4):

```
int   TmpCRC;
int   TmpLookupVal;     /* Lookup Table Value         */
int CRC32EthTbl[256] =
```

Those should all be `unsigned int`. Your current code propagates the sign bit into lower bits when performing `TmpCRC = TmpCRC >> 8U`